# Why Android U(android 14) inflating layout/views took more time than Android T(android 13)?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater, android-14

We found that it took more time for inflating layouts/views on Android Uthan Android T in our devices.
So I make an experiment with pixel Phone.

1. Firstly, I developed a demo app which just do inflate an specified layout. It included LinearLayouts/TextViews/Buttons/NumberPickers etc. And it'll output the total time the inflating took.
2. Then, installed the demo into both pixel 4(Android T system) and pixel 7(Android U system). Do the inflating operation.
   We can find that in Android U, it took 2-3 times time than Android T even the CPU working in much high freq in pixel 7.

**e.g. Inflating NumberPicker component:**
Pixel 7 inflating running on CPU 7 with freq 2.5GHz took about 2ms.
Well Pixel 4 inflating running on CPU 6 with freq 1.8GHz took about 0.8ms.

We got the same conclusion between pixel and our own device. It also makes jank issues in some Apps.

PS：Folowing is my test code. And you can input any layout id to do inflate and calc the time.

```
private long testInflateSpeed(int rId) {
    try {
        long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        inflater.inflate(rId, null);
        long endTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        return (endTime - startTime);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("DEBUG_INFLATE", "testInflateSpeed failed", ex);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

So anybody knows if there is something wrong about android U? And how to make optimize?